# How to convert a string of date and time in words to numbers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, time

I have the following string: `January 1, 2020 /  12:04 AM / a month ago`. How do I convert this into `1/1/2020 0:04:00`? The code should ignore the `a month ago`. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far where you might be getting an error ?

Comment: What exactly is the input and the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `dateutil`. It is a third part extension of datetime module. You can add it with
`python -m pip install python-dateutil`

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

data = 'January 1, 2020 / 12:04 AM / a month ago'

resp = parse(data, fuzzy_with_tokens=True)
print(resp[0]) # the first index is datetime object
```

The parser is relatively powerful. Here is documentation to [Parser](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html).

dateutil is one among many that can help you solve your problem. Good summary of tools such as maya, arrow etc are found [Stackabuse](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/) thanks to @WasabiMonster

Answer (score 0):

using `strptime` you can do it and below is the sample,i was using in my code

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(
...     "April 18, 2019, 09:09:09", "%B %d, %Y, %H:%M:%S"
```